# mysql "access denied for user" (only happens when connecting via php)

Tags: php, mysql, access-denied

I created user `dashboard` and granted it various privileges (such as `SHOW DATABASES`). I initially set the Host=[private ip of web-server], but kept getting access denied errors returned from php's `mysql_connect`, so I set `Host=192.168.%` so any machine on our network can access it.

I can successfully connect to the mysql Db on the Db server from my Mac using MySQLWorkbench (and successfully ran `SHOW DATABASES;`), but when I just try to connect via php on our webserver, I just get: `Access denied for user 'dashboard'@'192.168.xx.xx' (using password: YES)`

the code i'm using in php is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<head>
<?php
$dbhost = "192.168.x.x"; // but no x's
$dbuser = "dashboard";
$dbpass = "password"; // i copied&pasted the real password for other successful logins
$dbconnect = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die(mysql_error());
$query = mysql_query('SHOW DATABASES;');
?>
</head>
<body>
<? echo $query ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Semi-related note: Can I somehow set `$dbpass` equal to an encrypted string so it's not stored a plain-text?

**EDIT**: the mysql user is currently `dashboard@192.168.%` (not localhost)

**EDIT 2**: I thought since the Web Server is in the DMZ, that it might be communicating with MySQL from it's public IP, but when I change the host of `dashboard` to that, I get `Host '192.168.xx.xx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server`. So it seems that is not the case…

Comment: You have only defined user access for `dashboard@localhost`, you need to also grant user access to `dashboard@phpcomputer`, and log in with those credentials.

Comment: hi @Johan, thanks for your response, but no, it is not set to localhost. i initially created the user a `dashboard@webserver` and now have changed it to `dashboard@192.168.%.%` (which should allow any machine on our private network to connect as that user, right?).

Comment: Check - 1. is mysql listening on port OR socket? 2. Show us the privileges for this user 3. 192.168.x.x is local network

Comment: thanks for your response @ajreal. i figured out what was going on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354521/mysql-access-denied-for-user-only-happens-when-connecting-via-php/7363549#7363549

Comment: BTW you're missing an opening `<html>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The password contained a reserved character, so in PHP it needed to be enclosed with single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: What is a "reserved character"?

Comment: a special character the language uses for a specific purpose, such as @ to identify an array or a # to identify a hash (in perl)

Answer (score 0):

did you run

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO 'username'@'%'
```

or just the same, but @'localhost' ?

Comment: hi @user410932, I had tried that. It appears that I figured it out (see my answer above)