# Cannot connect to MySQL database on remote server using php mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, access-denied

I am trying to use mysqli to insert some data into a MySQL database (let's call the schema myDatabase), but cannot successfully connect. Here's the code snippet to connect:

```
...
$config = parse_ini_file('../includes/config.ini');
$username = $config['username'];
$password = $config['password'];
$dbname = $config['dbname'];
$server = $config['server'];
$conn = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$conn || $conn->connect_error)   {
  die( 'Connection Failed: ('.$conn->connect_errno.') '.$conn->connect_error);
}
...
```

I get the following result:

```
Connection Failed: (1045) Access denied for user 'myUser'@'my.laptop.ip.address' (using password: YES)
```

Here's some details on the set-up, in case they are relevant:
The code is on my laptop running Windows 7 and using PHP 5.3.5 that came with xammpp.
The database is hosted on a remote server with MySQL5.1.52.  I created a user to which I granted all privileges on myDatabase.*. No host was specified for the user (e.g. 'myUser'@'%'), as I am still in development and don't know the ip address where the code for the live application will be hosted.

If I ssh onto the database server, I can connect to mysql using the credentials for myUser and access the tables in myDatabase. I have another schema on this same server which is accessed by a different user, and have been able to use mysqli to connect without any problems.

Just to be sure it wasn't a typo, I dropped the user, and created it again, copying and pasting the username and password from the config.ini file used in my php code (and flushed privileges, of course). I did this again, except this time the host was specified, e.g.  CREATE USER 'myUser'@'my.laptop.ip.address' IDENTIFIED BY 'myPassword'. I keep getting the same error and now I'm completely stumped.

Help, please.

Comment: What does `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'myUser'@'my.laptop.ip.address'` show?

Comment: did you try connecting from `mysql` client from your local terminal to remote server ?

Comment: @Barmar,  `-----------------------------+
    | Grants for myUser@%

+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'myUser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'hashed myPassword' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'myDatabase'.* TO 'myUser'@'%'   `                     |

Comment: @Jigar, I connected to the remote server via ssh, and can log in to mysql as myUser

Comment: Sorry everyone, it appears this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354521/mysql-access-denied-for-user-only-happens-when-connecting-via-php?rq=1 , which I've only just seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this is strange, but it appears the problem had to do with the password I was using. The original one contained some special characters ($, & +). When I changed it so that it only contained numbers, letters and underscore, it worked.

Is this real, or did I accidentally do something else without realizing that turned out to be the actual solution?

Comment: Maybe the problem are on the form you stored the password. For these uses, store the password on a '' variable, not with "".

Answer (score 0):

On your mysql machine hit:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO 'myUser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

This will allow the user to connect from any host. Once it works, you can limit it to just a specific host and database.